# Find and replace the text in a cell with Google Script and Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet where I collect responses and another tab where I see a report for each record.

I want to add manually a number in the cell Writing Points (as in the image below) and click Update to update the cell of that specific record in the **responses** tab.

[image]

I managed to get the row number depending on the student the formula is:

`MATCH($D$3,Responses!D:D, 0)`

And the column is always BG of the repsonses tab.

How can I achieve this through Google script? I have an idea but I don't know how to do it.

My try:

```
row = MATCH($D$3,Responses!D:D, 0)
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('BG'+row).setValue(newwritingpoints);
```

I don't know how to conver the match formula into Google script syntax and how to copy and paste the value from that cell to the responses tab.

Google Sheet link:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dE6UVABhVp7WqEFdC0ptBK2ne6wEA6hCf0Wi6PxcMWE/edit#gid=2032966397

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- When `Update()` of Google Apps Script is run by the button, you want to retrieve the cells "D3" and "H24" in the sheet `Report`.
- You want to search the value of "D3" from the column "D" in the sheet `Responses`.
- When the value of "D3" and the values of column "D" in the sheet `Responses` are the same, you want to put the value of "H24" to the same row of the column "BG" in the sheet `Responses`.

For this, how about this answer? The flow of this sample script is as follows.

1. Retrieve the values from the cells "D3" and "H24" in the sheet `Report`.
2. Retrieve the values from the cells "D2:D" in the sheet `Responses`.
3. Create the range list from the retrieved values.
4. Put the value using the range list.

#### Sample script:

```
function Update() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  // 1. Retrieve the values from the cells "D3" and "H24" in the sheet `Report`.
  var reportSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Report");
  var searchText = reportSheet.getRange("D3").getValue();
  var writingPoints = reportSheet.getRange("H24").getValue();

  // 2. Retrieve the values from the cells "D2:D" in the sheet `Responses`.
  var responsesSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Responses");
  var values = responsesSheet.getRange("D2:D" + responsesSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();

  // 3. Create the range list from the retrieved values.
  var ranges = values.reduce((ar, [d], i) => {
    if (d == searchText) ar.push("BG" + (i + 2));
    return ar;
  }, []);

  // 4. Put the value using the range list.
  responsesSheet.getRangeList(ranges).setValue(writingPoints);
}
```

- In this script, it also supposes the case that the value of "D3" might find at several rows in the sheet `Responses`.

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [Class RangeList](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! This is exactly what I wanted!!!

Comment: @Registrar Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.